# Sql Developer : Exporting a XML from particular column in oracle db to excel sheet truncates some of the XML lines in the excel sheet

Tags: xml, oracle, excel, vba

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgP2T.png) screenshot shows the data retrieved.

I thought it was a problem with the excel sheet which cannot handle the XML size, but after I tried to paste a single xml manually to the excel sheet worked out.But when I try to do the same thing for hundreds of XML files using exporting option in sql developer to excel sheet truncates some of the lines.

Comment: This is ringing a bell but I can't find it... but I have a feeling it was either the SQL Developer version or Java/driver version. Are you using the latest version of SQL Devloper?

Comment: SQL developer Version 3.1.07